# Generics requires new class

Tags: java, generics

Consider the next method

```
<T, A extends BaseClass1, U extends BaseClass2<T, A>> 
void map(Class<T> classType, Class<U> myClass2Instance)
```

Then I got this class

```
class Child extends BaseClass2<ArrayList<MyData>, BaseClass1>
```

And now I am trying to do the mapping:

```
map(ArrayList<MyData>.class, Child.class)
```

Of curse its not compiling as you cant have generic class type, so I change it to the next statement:

```
Class<ArrayList<MyData>> classData = (Class<ArrayList<MyData>>) new ArrayList<MyData>().getClass();
map(classData, Child.class)
```

This rise a warning but it works.

**Is there any way to make it work without making new class instance**? I just don't like the new keyword here...

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, there's a warning again :)

Comment: @kocko I know, but OP explicitely asked for a way that does not create an instance. My comment is not an answer (and it even would not be a good suggestion).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose it's not compiling...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot get a variable of `Class<ArrayList<MyData>>` type without unchecked warnings.

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
Class<ArrayList<MyData>> classData = (Class<ArrayList<MyData>>) (Class) ArrayList.class;
```

And please note that `Class<ArrayList<MyData>>` is equal to `Class<ArrayList<AnyOtherData>>` because of type erasure, so won't be able to distinguish them in your `map` function.